# remove check_change event in page_load

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net checkbox control with check change event. When i change check it will call check_changed event.
But when reload it after check change event it automatically call the check_change event.
I don't want to call that check_change event in page_load another time.
Thanks

Comment: How do you reload the page? The problem is probably causes because you are re-posting the page. It would be nice if you could add a few code samples.

Comment: Both F5 and reload page call the check_changed event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this method

```
public  RestartPage()
{
Response.Redirect(Request.Url.PathAndQuery)}
```

and call this method after your event call
For more info follow this link
[remove check_change event in page load](http://forums.asp.net/p/1842974/5143995.aspx/1?Re%20remove%20check_change%20event%20in%20page_load)